Methods for utilizing machine learning models for prescriptive analytics
Can anyone provide support or resources that tackle the topic of using trained machine learning models to optimize your actions? i.e. how to go from predictive analytics to prescriptive analytics?
For example: you are trying to optimize data center energy usage. You build a model that accurately predicts data center energy usage based on historical data for a wide variety of input parameters. Now, how can you use that model to optimize your data center parameters to minimize the amount of energy that the data center uses? That's the kind of question that I'm looking for resources (Coursera, Youtube, Books, etc) on how to tackle.
Thank you for your time!
